# Dynamic query generation

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, t-sql

I'm trying to build a dynamic query in C# with Entity Framework. The end goal is to allow the user to build their own custom queries/reports in my app. I am getting this information from Angular and Typescript, and I have matching entities on both sides of my app (both frontend and backend). My goal here is to build a sql query string that I can later execute directly on the database. I am not currently concerned with validation, so for the time being, malformed queries are valid results (I will tackle this hurdle later - one step at a time). My entity is as follows:

```
 public class AdHocLine
    {
        //The table that we are selecting a column from
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "table")]
        public string table;
        //The column that a user wants to appear in their report
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
        public string column;
        //Any filter criteria (e.g. 'equals abcd', this would be the 'abcd')
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userCriteria")]
        public string userCriteria;
        //The operator being used (e.g. 'equals abcd', this would be 'equals'
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "op")]
        public string op;
        //If we are joining another column, this is the table we would be joining
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "joinTable")]
        public string joinTable;
        //If we are joining another column, this is the column we would be joining
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "joinColumn")]
        public string joinColumn;
        //Since this entity is meant to be delivered in an array, this is the array index
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "index")]
        public int index;
        //This is the column from our current table that we are joining on
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "joinWith")]
        public string joinWith;
    }
```

Is there anything that I'm missing in my entity that seems glaring?

Upon reviewing related questions, a use case may prove helpful. Say I want to select ProjectName (a string) from the table Project and want to include the column Description from its parent, ProgramElement (where Project has a guid pointing to the ProgramElement in question, called ProgramElementId). The result should look something like the following:

```
 SELECT t1.ProjectName, t2.Description FROM Project as t1, ProgramElement as t2 <additional where clause information belongs here>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that user determined ad-hoc querying is almost always very bad idea. You are essentially giving your users the capability to crash your system with a poorly formed query. It is a much safer option to determine, up front, what will be needed and use parameterized stored procedures or "canned" queries to access the data. Although it takes more time and forethought, "canned" reports are much safer, and almost always much more performant than ad-hoc. That being said, I don't see anything glaring missing from your class.

Comment: Thanks! The only reason I'm allowing AdHoc queries is because it was specified in my requirements document, specifically requested by the customer. The customer is used to having direct DB access, so I'm trying to pare that down to just selects and report generation. Since we're still in a pre-release phase, it's ok if it's still a bit rough or slow. These are things that we can clean up later. You make a good point though, I may talk to my team lead about trying to convince the customer that 'Canned' reports might be better.

Comment: @AndrewM.  What exactly are you asking here?  Without knowing how detailed your resultant queries need to be, there is no way we can tell you if something is missing.  Do they need to be able to left, right, cross joins?  Applys?  Call functions or stored procedures?  Declare variables?  Create temporary tables?  Use `CASE` statements?  Because all of that is currently lacking.

Comment: As long as this is just internal reporting and they are used to having access to the database it might be worthwhile to consider just letting them use an existing reporting tool to generate their own reports. One option would be MS Access. There used to be a data project type (not sure what it is in the current version) which would let you connect to a SQL database and build reports.

Comment: @iamdave - Currently, the user just has the ability to run select statements. They will need to be able to join (though I can specify which joins they're restricted to) but they don't need to be able to use Applys, call functions or stored procedures, declare variables, etc.

Comment: @SMM - Thanks for the heads up. We're actually moving the customer away from having them use Access so we can more tightly control access to the database. That's why we have the restriction of selects only in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something a bit more elaborate than this from the SQL server side and my first advice would be don't

But if you must...

The obvious omission is some way of specifying the JOIN type

```
SELECT t1.ProjectName, t2.Description 
FROM Project as t1
JOIN ProgramElement as t2  ON t2.joinColumn = t1.joinWith
<additional where clause information belongs here>
```

or

```
SELECT t1.ProjectName, t2.Description 
FROM Project as t1
LEFT JOIN ProgramElement as t2  ON t2.joinColumn = t1.joinWith
<additional where clause information belongs here>
```

Also Would it not make more sense to have an array of columns to include as opposed to a column property. They're probably going to ask for multiple columns eventually so you may as well be ready.

For that matter you should probably have an array of columns from the second table

But really it looks like you need to kick back against the specifications

Comment: I talked to my team lead, and it looks like there's no way around having ad hoc queries. I'll be heading in the multiselect direction in the near future since I think that it will be more useful and perhaps easier anyway. The column from the second table indicates which column the user would like to join on, so multiple columns may prove problematic. Thanks for your advice, I'll probably look in to specifying the join type.